# trying to copy from root to user

Tags: mount, tar

I mounted a folder inside my C drive to a root path of mnt/myFolder

now I am trying to copy the contents of that folder to /home/dev/build/mysource

I used that command that was taught by my senior inside the folder that I want to copy but it is not working as the error I am getting is

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

can you please help me understand why this is happening ?

this is my command:

```
 tar cvf - * : (cd /home/dev/build/mysource; tar xf -)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a typo in your command:

```
tar cvf - * | ( cd /home/dev/build/mysource; tar xfp -)
```

(use the piping symbol `|` instead of a colon `:`)